# python error in zope- Prints, but never reads 'printed' variable

Tags: python, zope

Im new to python and zope. In the ZMI I have created a new python script with the following code:

```
the_message = 'hello there human'

print the_message
```

I am unable to save the file as it gives the error 'Prints, but never reads 'printed' variable'.

If I use `return the_message` then it saves and displays fine.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here? is there something I need to add to my script that im missing?

Comment: @Ofiris: No, python 2, this is Zope. The OP is talking about restricted python scripts edited through the Zope web server. See http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/BasicScripting.html#using-python-based-scripts

Comment: @lukeocorn: Are you returning the `printed` variable?

Comment: no. The script is as you see it above. Adding a return statement doesn't work either.

Comment: So `print the_message` then `return printed` does *not* work?

Comment: that does work. Sorry I miss understood your question. I was typing 'return the_message' and not 'return printed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *explicitly* return `printed`:

```
the_message = 'hello there human'

print the_message

return printed
```

The `printed` variable is not implicitly read. See [Print Statement Support](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/BasicScripting.html#print-statement-support) in the Basic Scripting chapter of the Zope 2 book.